# Forward declaration of class / Invalid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors

I have six classes, obviously this isn't my actual code, just a simple version

BaseA:

```
class BaseA {
public:
    BaseA();
    virtual ~BaseA();
    void update() { // the body functions would normally be in a seperate file
        for (auto iter : list_of_bs) {
            iter->update();
        }
    }
private:
    vector<BaseB*>* list_of_bs;
};
```

BaseB:

```
class BaseB {
public:
    BaseB();
    virtual ~BaseB();
    void update() { // the body functions would normally be in a seperate file
        for (auto iter : list_of_cs) {
            iter->update();
        }
    }
private:
    vector<BaseC*>* list_of_cs;
};
```

BaseC

```
class BaseC {
public:
    BaseC();
    virtual ~BaseC();
    void update() { // the body functions would normally be in a seperate file
        // do whatever
    }
};
```

Then I have three other classes, A, B, and C that inherit each of their respective base classes. I add an instance of B or C the list_of_bs/list_of_cs so it can have its own code to be run when the update function is called.

The problem is, it comes up with errors "Forward declaration of class / Invalid use of incomplete type" in various files. How can I set up my system so that it doesn't have these errors?

If you want to see my actual code, you can find it here: https://github.com/Ja-ake/openworld

Read the README.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you are getting is the result of using a forward declaration and then trying to call a method or access a member without providing the full declaration.

The fix is to make sure you always `#include` the `.h` file containing the full class definition (not necessarily the `cc` file that contains the method definitions) before calling any method on the class.

Comment: I've done this, I think the problem is that each file includes a bunch of other files and there is a lot of overlap, causing some of the classes to not have access to the full definition of the class (because of the preprocessor directives preventing double inclusion of header files)

Comment: @Jake, Please make your minimum example reproducible. Apologies but I'd rather not try to understand the logic of your actual program.

Comment: I figured out the problem while setting up the minimum example, thank you for having me do this! The problem was that I had a class that depended on another class that depended on the first class, but all of this happened through a bunch of inheritances, so I didn't realize that I had done that.